# using vue or jquery in laravel mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js

any body can help me, how to use vue.js or jquery in laravel mix, first i install laravel and i run npm install, so automatic using laravel mix
but how to use vue js or jquery, i try very simple vue js but its not working

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#coba',
    data:{
        title : "my title"
    }
});
```

code above i write in resource/js/app.js
and when i call in view

````
<div id="coba">
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</div>
```
its does not working
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using blade template so you must prepend the variable with `@`

```
<div id="coba">
        <h3>@{{title}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: @yokana alright. Please mark as solved if it did answered your query, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'npm run watch'. It compiles your app.js from resources to public folder. Make sure your file names match up. (The one you compile in laravel mix (app.js) and the one you include in your script tag source attribute.):

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"><script>
```

Comment: already mention in parent view and i extend those view  @extends('layouts.app'), but still not working